# Assign different id to the same element inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am rending this component `Card` inside map function. What I'm trying to achieve is to assign a different id to Card, each time the loop renders it. So basically all the Cards rendered will have a different id.

I want to change the color of icon (`FontAwesomeIcon`) on the Card component to red when a user clicks on. This is the Card Component -

```
   <div className='Card'>

      <div className='cardimg'>
        <img src={props.product.image} alt='55' />
      </div>

      <p>{props.product.title}</p>

      <div className='flex'>
        <p>${props.product.price}</p>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className='icon1' id={Math.random} onClick={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.id);
          document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.color = 'red'
        }} icon={faHeart} />
      </div>
  </div>
```

The icon :

```
<FontAwesomeIcon className='icon1' id={Math.random} onClick={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.id);
          document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.color = 'red'
        }} icon={faHeart} />
```

Here is Component that renders Card

```
 <div className='Results'>
        {console.log(props.f1)}
        {props.allproducts ? props.allproducts.map(e => {

            if (e.title.toUpperCase().includes(props.value.toUpperCase()))

                if ((props.f1.length !=0 ?  ((e.category==props.f1[0]) || (e.category==props.f1[1]) || (e.category==props.f1[2]) || (e.category==props.f1[3])) : true) && (props.f2[0] ? (e.price > props.f2[0] && e.price < props.f2[1]) : true) )
                    {return <Card product={e} key={e.id}/>}


        }) : ''}
    </div>
```

What I've tried:
Assigning a random value using Math.random function.
Sending a unique value through props and assigning it to id.

would also appreciate if there's a different way to achieve this.

Comment: something like `{return <Card product={e} key={`card-${e.id}`}/>}` ?

Comment: why not just use `e.currentTarget.style.color` to change colour of the clicked element instead of getting the id from the target and then re-getting the target?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key prop to transfer id to card

```
<div className='Card'>

      <div className='cardimg'>
        <img src={props.product.image} alt='55' />
      </div>

      <p>{props.product.title}</p>

      <div className='flex'>
        <p>${props.product.price}</p>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className='icon1' id={"icon_"+props.key} onClick={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.id);
          document.getElementById("icon_"+props.key).style.color = 'red'
        }} icon={faHeart} />
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's just changing the icon of first Card to red, not the Card I'm clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with an `useState` hook object:

```
const [cardClicked, setCardClicked] = useState({})

// rest of youre code

return (
  <>
    // some nice jsx
    {xyz.map((element, index) => {
      const id = `${element.name}_${index}`;
      return (
        <Card key={id} id={id} onClick={() => setCardClicked({ ...cardClicked, [id]: cardClicked[id] ? false : true)}>
          .....
          <Icon style={{ color: cardClicked[id] ? "red" : "blue" }} />
          .....
        </Card>
      )
    })}
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to change the color of `FontAwesomeIcon` when the user clicks on the icon. You should have the unique `ids` in the `array` that are on the `map`, then you need to create a [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), where you store the `id` when the user clicks on the icon, and then you make a [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in `className`, as you can see the code below, I hope this is the best way.

```
const [id, setId] = useState(null);

<FontAwesomeIcon className={`icon1 ${id === props.product.id ? 'red' : ''}`} id={Math.random} onClick={(e) => {
    setId(props.product.id);
}} icon={faHeart} />
```